# PHP date function not converting date string correctly

Tags: php, date

I am experiencing a weird problem in creating date formats from date strings. An example date string in my code is `October 21, 2006`. When I convert this to date using PHP `date` and `strtotime` function I always get current Year for year instead of the year originally present in date string.

Here it is:

```
$date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime('21 October,2006')); //Returns 2015-10-21 instead of 2006-10-21
```

What I am doing wrong?

Please note I always get the date string from user in this way i.e `Day Full Month Name, Year` from the datepicker and I cannot change that.

Comment: As you already noticed `strtotime()` doesn't understand your date format. Take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Sorry, But get output as "2006-10-21" so what is incorrect ?

Comment: I also get the output as 2006-10-21.Which PHP version

Comment: This is weird. I am using PHP  5.4...But getting 2015-10-21.Believe me :)

Comment: [Check this](https://3v4l.org/noPnE) @Jalpa

Comment: [Check this](https://3v4l.org/noPnE) @sinaza

Comment: [Check this](https://3v4l.org/noPnE) @TamilSelvan

Comment: oh 1+ then :D. How about use a couple of `explode`s separating by space and comma then try re-ordering

Comment: Thanks guys for suggestions. I have used the function  suggested by Rizier123. Thanks Uchiha for the demonstration.